# Eclipse formatter for getter/setter to single line?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I tell (if ever) Eclipse to make a single line for a getter or setter when using auto formatting?

```
public User getUser() {
   return user;
}
```

to:

```
public User getUser() { return user; }
```

Comment: I'm with you on this one. These ugly getters and setters are taking so much screen realestate and bring exactly 0 information. Unfortunately, this is so against the kosher Java that I'm afraid we won't see it soon in Eclipse formatter.

Comment: It looks like you can edit the format via Code Template but only the body or comment not in its entirety.

Comment: You might be able to do it with a combination of regular "Templates" (e.g. `syso`) and the use of `@formatter:off` (because this gets formatted). However, you would need to create each getter/setter manually.

Comment: In IntelliJ I just collapse/fold those getters and setters, which makes them a one-liner (this is a separate setting in IntelliJ to do this automatically for simple property accessors). I would be surprised if Eclipse doesn't have a similar setting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't like all the boilerplate which Java forces you to write, you might be interested in [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) as an alternative solution.

Instead of trying to format your code to minimize the visual impact of getters and setters, Project Lombok allows them to be added by the compiler behind the scenes, guided by annotations on your class's fields.

Instead of writing a class like this:

```
 public class GetterSetterExample {
   private int age = 10;
   private String name;

   public int getAge() {
     return age;
   }

   public void setAge(int age) {
     this.age = age;
   }

   protected void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
   }
 }
```

You would write:

```
 import lombok.AccessLevel;
 import lombok.Getter;
 import lombok.Setter;

 public class GetterSetterExample {
   @Getter @Setter private int age = 10;
   @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED) private String name;
 }
```

(example from: http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html)

Comment: @membersound Lombok adds the getter/setter methods to the compiled bytecode automatically. So you can call the generated getter/setter methods as if they were explicitly in the source code. So yes, this should work with junit unit tests. If you haven't already, I'd highly suggest listening to the video on the home page: http://projectlombok.org/. It gives a nice, concise description of how Lobmok works and what it can do. After that i'd suggest trying it on a small dummy/sample project (not your main codebase) to see if you like it.

Comment: @membersound, my advice: use normal getters/setters, but put them on the end of your code

Comment: @smas a healthy fear of frameworks that perform behind-the-scenes annotation based processing on top of standard Java compilation is definitely a good thing and I certainly I don't use Lombok for all or even most Java code I write. Still, I think it's a clever tool and might be just the ticket for someone who really doesn't like getter/setter/hashCode/equals boilerplate spewed all over their data classes :)

Comment: @ulmangt I have used lombok setter in my parent class. But I cannot call the setter method of the parent class from the child class constructor.

Comment: @ulmangt - Can the lombok annotations be used along with jackson (json to java) ? I suspect that it might prevent jackson from serializing jackson annotated java class to json string.

Answer (score 4):

Java code formatting in Eclipse does not differentiate between getters/setters and any other methods in a class. So this cannot be done by built-in eclipse formatting.

Comment: I believe Eclipse can't differentiate between getter/setter you create versus other existing methods. However, I'm certainly sure Eclipse knows when you use "Source > Generate getters and setters"

Answer (score 4):

As other posters have stated, Eclipse cannot currently do this.  There is a feature request at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=205973 however, and if it gets enough upvotes there's a chance somebody might implement it...

Comment: Excellent - actually the request includes _any_ one liner method which is exactly what I wanted

Comment: The bug has been fixed around 2018... [https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=205973](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=205973). Latest comment: "Verified for 4.10 M3 with build id I20181120-1800" dated "2018-11-21 01:51:43 EST"

Answer (score 4):

How about using formatter on/off tags:

```
//@formatter:off
@override public final String getName() {return this.name;}
//@formatter:on
```

You will need to make sure that the on/off tags are enabled (preferences/java/code style/formatter/edit/on off tags).  This may be the default.

For just one method it will be just as ugly as a three line getter method, but if you have more than four or five then it will look neater.
It also allows you to group the getters and setters for a property together rather than all the getters and then all the setters.

That is my solution, anyway.

Comment: This is a good compromise. I'm already putting a pseudo region block (e.g. C#'s #region metadata) to demarcate my getters/setters. It'll be easy to add the formatter tags to it too.